# How to display/mask part of an Image without scaling - QtQuick/QML

Tags: qt, audio, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I'm trying to make a simple audio meter with QtQuick. The meter graphic comes from a PNG file, and when the level changes, I want to change the height of the displayed part of the image, without scaling it at all. I simply want to mask some of the image off without changing it.

I have tried the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 482
    Image {
        x: 165
        source: "meter.png"
        fillMode: Image.Pad
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        height: 482
    }
    Image {
        x: 175
        source: "meter.png"
        fillMode: Image.Pad
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        height: 440
    }
    Image {
        x: 185
        source: "meter.png"
        fillMode: Image.Pad
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        height: 400
    }
}
```

But this gives the following undesried results, with some kind of scaling happening. I want where the yellow and green meet in all 3 images to be identical.

[image: Meter attempt]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Image component fills from top to bottom by default, but instead of wrapping Image in an outer Item, and using clip which is bad for performance, just add to all your Image items :

```
width: sourceSize.width; // to be sure the width is the exact same as the source
verticalAlignment: Image.AlignBottom; // to force image to start from the bottom
```

So the content will not be scaled and aligned to the bottom of your Image.

Answer (score 0):

The `Image` Item fills its content top-down, so if you want to anchor it to the bottom you will need an additional container Item to clip out the Image's top portion:

```
Item {
  x: 165
  width: childrenRect.width
  height: 482

  clip: true  // This is the key

  Image {
      source: "meter.png"
      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
  }
}
```

Comment: I consider this not to be the best answer possible :
- childrenRect is not fast, and clip drops down drawing perf too
- it adds a needless nesting level in the code

Take a look at my answer for the minimal code for this ;-)

Comment: I do agree. Didn't know about that `verticalAlignment` property applied to an `Image` Item.